# Insert/append matrix into matrix iteratively

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to add a 3d matrix in the end to a 4D Matrix:
like this:

```
v=VideoReading('video.avi');
mat3d = zeros([n m 3],'double');
mat4d = zeros([n m 3 2],'double');
for i=1:10
mat3d = read(v,i);
mat4d = ????;
end
l=size(mat4d);
```

I would like to have the 10 frames added in the mat4d, l=[n m 3 12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution :

```
mat4d(:,:,:,i) = mat3d;
```

quite simply !

Answer (score 1):

To get these frames most specifically these 10, you need to put a command like this:

```
mat4d = read(v,[3 13]); 
[n,m] = size(mat4d)
```